# Read content from a github file and post as data in a curl request

Tags: curl

I have a file with some raw data at github

How do I get curl to first download that file, read its contents and then post it as part of the `--data` field

I tried `curl --data @<url> <host>` but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Why not run curl twice, first to GET the data, then to POST it?

Comment: @evilSnobu  I'm not a linux expert.. what would be a one-liner to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against a one-liner since there are many things that could go wrong, for example your expect binary data and some text error body comes back instead.

```
# GET your source
curl -si -o out.txt https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../file.json

# Some logic here to test your download is what you expect it to be

# POST it
curl -si --data @file.json -H 'Content-type: application/json' <your POST url>
```

If you expect binary data you should replace Content-type in the POST operation with `application/octet-stream`.

```
-s   for silent
-i   for printing response headers and status code
```